# "declaration is incompatible with "void Student::update()" " Showing this error at 41st line. how to correct it?

Tags: c++, oop

**code**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std ;
    
    class Student{
        public:
        int id;
        string name;
        int  roll;
        static string school;
        static int class;
        
        void input();
        void output();
        static void update();
    
    
    };
    
    string Student::school = "PPS";
    int Student::class = 7;
    
    
    
    void Student::update(int x){
        class=8;
    }
    
    int main(){
        Student s;
        return 0;
    }
```

**issue**

"declaration is incompatible with "void Student::update()" (declared at line 16) " showing this error.

1. I want to declare a variable in the the function which is present in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Compare

```
static void update()
```

to

```
void Student::update(int x)
```

Note how one has an `int` parameter and one doesn't.
Since you don't access it in your implementation of `update`, I suppose it should be removed in the definition.